# Take value from specific column for each row

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have array `X`  with some values

```
[[0.3,0.4,0.5],
 [0.1,0.7,0.9],
.
.
.
[0.3,0.6,0.9]]
```

an I have array with indexes `I =[0,2,1,2,0,..]`.

I would like to take value from array `X` for each row according to indexed in array `I` like, in array `I` first value is `0` so from first row in `I` will take value from column `0` which is `0.3` and so on.
Is there any possible to do this without loop?

My idea:
`Y = X[:,I]` has no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there, what you need is some fancy indexing on top:

```
Y = X[np.arange(len(I)),I]
```

This kind of indexing tells numpy to select the entries `(i, I(i))` in `X`.

Comment: perfect :) I would not figure this out by my self. Thank You!

Comment: If you never faced it, you can't know it :)